# Why does my Thrift (c_glib) client fail with an "invalid pointer" error?

Tags: c, thrift, glib

I'm creating a simple thrift server/client program in C (g_lib).
This is how my thrift IDL file looks like:

```
namespace cpp tutorial

service Calculator {
    void ping(),
    binary getdata()    
}
```

And the implementation for getdata on the thrift server looks like this:

```
    static gboolean
    tutorial_calculator_handler_getdata (CalculatorIf  *iface,
                                      GByteArray        *_return,
                                      GError       **error)
    {
      THRIFT_UNUSED_VAR (iface);
      THRIFT_UNUSED_VAR (error);

      puts ("getdata()");

      GByteArray *gbarray;
      gint i;

      gbarray = g_byte_array_new ();
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          g_byte_array_append (gbarray, (guint8*) &i, 1);

      *_return = *gbarray;

      return TRUE;
    }
```

Now, on the client side, I'm calling the getdata as follows:

```
....
....
GByteArray *data;
....
....

if (!error && calculator_if_getdata (client, &data, &error)) {
  puts ("getdata()");      

}
```

Unfortunately, the client crashes with the following message in the calculator_if_getdata call:

```
*** Error in `./client': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xb741742d ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is this the correct way to send an array of integers from the server to client in thrift? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after spending some time on it, here's the working handler and the client side implementation code:

```
gboolean 
tutorial_calculator_handler_getdata (CalculatorIf *iface,
                                 GByteArray ** _return,                                 
                                 GError **error)
{
  THRIFT_UNUSED_VAR (iface);
  THRIFT_UNUSED_VAR (error);

  GByteArray *thing = g_byte_array_new();
  *_return = g_byte_array_new();
  guint8 i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){    
    g_byte_array_append (thing, (guint8*) &i, sizeof(guint8));
  }

  g_byte_array_append(*_return, (guint8*) thing->data, thing->len);


  return TRUE;
}
```

And the client side:

```
GByteArray *data = g_byte_array_new();
if (!error && calculator_if_getdata (client, &data, &error)) {
    puts ("getdata()");
    printf ("Data : %d\n", data);
    guint8 i;
    guint8 size = sizeof(guint8);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      printf ("Data : %d\n", data->data[size*i]);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues with what you're doing here:

- If a service method returns a complex type, the `_return` parameter passed to its handler function will point to a *pre-allocated* structure that should not be destroyed or re-created. Your code should be appending values to the `GByteArray` to which `_return` already points, not creating a `GByteArray` of its own.
- Although you shouldn't be trying to modify the value of `_return` anyway, the way your code does this is incorrect and ends up clobbering the data structure to which `_return` points. This most likely explains the error message you're seeing.
- Your code declares `i` a thirty-two bit integer but appends to the byte array only `i`'s first byte. This will not have the effect you intend on every machine architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the response Simon, Please see the inline questions::

Comment: If i simply printf("%u\n", *_return); it prints out 0, which means i guess the function did not pre-allocated any structure for it.

Now, if i allocate a GByteArray myself (*_return = g_byte_array_new ();) for the return then it seems to be working (at least nothing crashes).

The only problem I'm having now is the client isnt receiving proper data. You can find the modified version over here http://pastebin.com/HCwehPvR  Also, thrift repository doesn't contain a test case or example for binary data. I think i can add it to the repo once i get it working.

Comment: Good! You're right; `binary` is a base type, not a complex one (i.e. not a collection) so what I wrote above is incorrect.